# Ionic 2: LocalStorage between pages

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, local-storage, ionic2, angular-local-storage

My app has two pages, I want to save data of the application using localstorage.

Here is my first page:

```
constructor(public nav : NavController){

    this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
    this.array = [];
    this.nav = nav;
    this.information= this.local.get('obj'); 
    this.array.push(this.information);  //storing data in array from locals
    console.log(this.array);
}

gotopage(){
    this.nav.push(SecPage);   //going to second page where input fields are
}
```

This is how I am using localstorage for setting data in the second page where the input fields are as follows.

constructor:

```
this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
```

onSubmit method

```
this.local.set('obj', value);
this.navigation.pop();
```

Now I want to display data from the array of the first page but nothing is displayed.

```
<ion-card *ngFor= "#arr of array">
<img src=""/>
<ion-card-content>
<ion-card-title>
{{arr.name}}
</ion-card-title>
</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

I guess there is problem of persistence when I'm coming from the second page to first page. Could you identify why data from the array is not displaying?

Comment: I think you're doing it opposite. `localStorage` is global not the `array`.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.local.getItem('obj')
  .then(
     this.information=data;
  );
```

Check if you get data from the storage in right way.

```
console.log(this.information)
```